# Prevent accounts that are suspended network-wide from creating more site profiles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, account-suspension

Once in a while someone misbehaves on multiple sites at the same time, usually by posting spam or offensive content. We have the ability to apply a network-wide suspension in those cases and it is prominently annotated on every site profile belonging to the same account:

> This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on $time.

However, this suspension only applies to the site profiles that the offending user has at that time.

We have over 100 sites now, so it would be great if a network-wide suspension also prevented people from creating new site profiles linked to the same account. Alternatively, having the suspension auto-apply to these new profiles would be fine as well.

Comment: I vote for the second, along with a subscript saying `haha sucker we know who you are!`. (On a unrelated note, I may or may-not of had to deal with a massive amount of spam the last couple days.)

Comment: How often do network-wide suspension actually happen, I've only seen them used two times now, they seem to be rather rare

Comment: @MadScientist They are pretty rare, yeah. Suspensions are supposed to be exceptional to begin with, and network-wide suspensions are even more unusual. Usually folks keep their misbehaving to one site at a time.

Comment: This should be done anyway, but in practice I don't see how it's going to matter much, since the OP can just use a different OpenID if they're really serious about creating a new profile.

Comment: I thought spammers accounts just get deleted, is there change in policy to put them under suspension instead? For the record, I'm all for the suggestion and prefer the second option: let them create the profile but have it insta-pended. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Most spammers are just "driving by" and should be just destroyed.

Comment: @MadScientist: In the past week I've seen a viable candidate for a network suspension crop up in TL every two days.

Comment: @Anna what's your current policy for network-wide suspended users who did open new account elsewhere? Do you hunt them down? While looking into that I stumbled upon [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1252742/cprogcr?tab=summary) who opened [that account](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/33557/cprogcr) afterwards.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd We reapply the network-wide suspension to catch new accounts if/when we notice.

Comment: @AdamLear any change in code might have broken something? [Network wide suspensions with greater than 1 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353659/network-wide-suspensions-with-greater-than-1-reputation-points)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has been completed.

- Upon a network-wide suspension all current accounts are suspended
- All accounts created by the same user are suspended upon creation
- All the accounts (original and newly created) are unbanned at the same time