# How does a network-wide suspension work when the account is unsuspended on at least one site?

Tags: support, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

I've run into an account that seems to be hitting some edge cases with the network wide suspension process.

From what I understand, [accounts with a network-wide suspension are prevented from creating new profiles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177800/prevent-accounts-that-are-suspended-network-wide-from-creating-more-site-profile).  But how does this work for creating new accounts, if the user is unsuspended on at least one site?  Can new accounts be created, and used with impunity?  How does this work?

Answer (score 9):

That's not an accurate summary of the other question. While that's what the request asked for, that's not quite what was implemented.

Users can create profiles whenever they want, they just get automatically suspended so long as there is an active network suspension. If one site unsuspends the user, then that profile is unsuspended. We don't attempt to automatically reapply network suspensions throughout its course - it's only applied network-wide at the time it's issued and to new profiles as they are created.

The unsuspension on another site has no effect whatsoever on the status of the suspension on the network account, and new profiles will continue being auto-suspended until its end.

Comment: So each account creation requires a manual unsuspension upon the target site?  Just wanna make sure I have that clear, in which case this is more or less a non-issue.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes, it would. E.g. if their profile on the site where they were unsuspended got deleted and recreated, it would get automatically suspended again too.