# Network wide suspensions with greater than 1 reputation points

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, reputation, account-suspension

I found a user with a network wide suspension but having >1 reputation on 2 sites.

[image]

Upon request by Staff/Moderator I can provide the user address if it is a bug but at the moment
**I am looking forward to know** how is this possible.

Comment: Yeah 101 rep means they created the account while being already suspended, most likely. Maybe the network wide suspension will "catch" and suspend there soon too, but it should be instant. Adding a bug tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizardWearingMask Thanks, do you think it would be appropriate to flag my post with the user ID so that the tag is retained on the forum and I dont loose it

Comment: Yes this can't hurt.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was very likely a race condition completely at my own fault. I triggered an account merge almost immediately after issuing the network suspension, which caused the account's Id number to change and for the code to fail to network-suspend the remainder of the profiles. I should have waited until all the profiles were suspended before doing that.

Comment: Ohhh this makes it clear. But still a bug to be fixed? the person could still use the indicated 2 forums dodging the network ban (unless I notified here on MSE)

Comment: @Cagliostro I deleted the unsuspended profiles because they were empty. But there's not any way to fix doing something that interrupts another process other than training the humans not to do that.

Comment: @Cagliostro: One fixed bug (with a regression test) might prevent 100 bugs down the line from ever reaching users (thus freeing up time for adding or improving features).