# Account said to be suspended network-wide, but it's not

Tags: support, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

There is a user account that has a suspension message on Mi Yodeya that says they are suspended network-wide until 2025. However, they have several other accounts, and *none* of them appear to be suspended. The user voted to close a question on Mathematics today, so they are clearly not suspended. Is this suspension message specific to the site? Did the moderators for the site erroneously choose this message, or does it not mean what I think it means? The other possibility is that it is a bug and that they are *supposed* to be suspended network-wide, but are not.

This may not be a duplicate of [User is suspended network-wide, except not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257498/user-is-suspended-network-wide-except-not-really), since the user is suspended "network-wide" on just *one* site, not *all sites but a few*. In that case, the user in question had been manually unsuspended on *just one* site by a moderator there. While it might be possible that local moderators unsuspended the user on all of their other sites but one, this may not be the case here.

Comment: Related? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353659/network-wide-suspensions-with-greater-than-1-reputation-points

Comment: @Ollie I wasn't sure if it was appropriate to single out the user, so I didn't link to the profile.

Comment: Well, you'd have to do something **_really_** bad to get network wide suspensions. **_REALLY_** BAD. Can you screenshot the message?

Comment: This seems related:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257498/user-is-suspended-network-wide-except-not-really, but the status there is status-bydesign.  Weird.

Comment: @10Repisn'tactiveonMSE sort of - kind of...for five years, yes.

Comment: The user also has well over 100 reputation on all their other communities, rather than the suspension-standard 1, so something is clearly skewed.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I doubt this is a duplicate. In this case, the user is suspended "network-wide" on just *one* account, not *all but a few* accounts. While it might be the case that local moderators unsuspended the user on all of their sites but one, I think the chances of that case here are low and there might be something else going on.

Comment: Also, I did [an SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/386720/find-all-userids-across-databases-for-an-account-id) and they don't have any hidden communities that are suspended.

Comment: @sonic see the accepted answer. It's a duplicate.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Thanks; voted this as a duplicate. I didn't know that it was an instance of the same case here, but now I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is this suspension message specific to the site? Did the moderators for the site erroneously choose this message, or does it not mean what I think it means?

The network-wide suspension message is not a choice to moderators. It is automatically applied when a staff member actually does apply a network-wide suspension.

---

I found the user you are referring to. They were suspended network-wide by staff, and their remaining profiles were manually unsuspended afterwards. The message is technically correct, they do have a network suspension at the account level and if the user ever created a new profile, it would be automatically suspended for the remainder of that term. But for obvious reasons, there's not any other detail I can go into about their situation.

Comment: I'm curious: Are site moderators able to locally unsuspend a user who has a network-wide suspension, or can such an unsuspension only be performed by staff?

Comment: @RyanM Moderators can manually unsuspend a network-suspended account, yes.

Comment: @RyanM also see the duplicate question, this is explained there.